# Xcode: Build Settings - Other Linker Flags: What is -licucore?

Tags: xcode, compiler-flags, build-settings

-licucore was already in Other Linker Flags for a target that I added to my project. Isn't it normally blank?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libicucore` is the Mac OS X regexp library. Don't know why it's already included in your project perhaps your settings have been modified from the defaults.

Comment: Oh yeah, it was added to the main target for `RegexKitLite`. I'm not sure how it got into the new target I added. Anyway, I removed it cause that target's not using `RegexKitLite`. Sweet! Thanks!